# Using the STUFF function in update

Tags: sql-server, stuff

Can someone tell me why this use of the `STUFF` function will not work?

```
UPDATE table
SET STUFF(address, LEN(TRIM(address)) - 2, 2, 'Drive')
WHERE RIGHT(TRIM(address), 3) =' DR'
```

Is it because the insert would essentially be a concatenation?

Can someone please provide me with a solution to get this working?

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Please explain what "will not work" means.

Comment: Learn this lesson well. "does not work" is never a useful comment to make in a public forum where readers do not know what you are trying to accomplish, cannot see your screen, and cannot run whatever code you might provide.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious issue is that you meed to assign the value:

```
UPDATE table
    SET address = STUFF(address, LEN(TRIM(address))-2, 2, 'Drive')
    WHERE RIGHT(TRIM(address),3) = ' DR';
```

Comment: Ouch. Didn't have my morning coffee yet. THANKS LOL